# Facade vs app. A bit confused

Tags: php, laravel

Wouldn't `app()` almost the same to `Facade::method()` ?

I think I'm missing something here. To me I find it almost the same as they are `global` like calls.

Why bother using `app()` instead of `Facade::method()` then?

Comment: `app()->method()` would be the same as `Application::method()` but not all facades are backed by a helper function (which is what `app()` is really). For example you can use `Mail::send...` but there's no `mail()` function that does the same thing (such a function would conflict with PHPs mail function I guess).

Comment: @apokryfos ok aside from that. I see some people arguing about facade as a bad thing and should use app() instead. Why?

Comment: That's really an odd thing unless you mean using the service container to resolve instances instead of using facades. Then it makes more sense I guess.

Comment: @apokryfos I saw the discussion here: http://programmingarehard.com/2014/01/11/stop-using-facades.html/ I get both sides' points (empathy thing and ease of use) but what I don't understand is they're seems similar to me in terms of usage.

Comment: What I read from the discussion if anything is the only reason not to use Facades is because only Laravel uses them while the IoC pattern is more widely used. I guess that makes sense, but whether you find that argument convincing to get you to stop using them is really up to you.